# compare value inside the HastSet

Tags: java

I have three files in my parent directory which are

```
c:/test/abc.png
c:/test/gibby.png
c:/test/cisco.doc
```

The `FileVisitResult` will visit my parent directory for any files that stay inside the directory, it's will pick up the file with full path and send it to my `subfunction` class for further processing. But i found out the `cisco.doc` have been sent to the `subfunction` class twice. There will be a problem if the quantity of the files start to grow. 
 This is my source code

```
            while(true)
            {
                        try {
                            Files.walkFileTree(ParentDir, new FileVisitor<Path>()
                                    {

                                        @Override
                                        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path sub, IOException exc) throws IOException
                                        {
                                              return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path sub, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
                                        {
                                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
                                        {
                                            Path tempPath1;
                                            System.out.println("@The abs path of the file is"+file);
                                            java.util.Iterator<Path> it = MyFileList.iterator();
                                            while(it.hasNext())
                                            {
                                                tempPath1 = it.next();
                                                if(tempPath1 == null)  //first round
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("empty list");
                                                    MyFileList.add(file);
                                                }
                                                else if(tempPath1 == file) //after first round
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("same in the list : "+file);
                                                }
                                                else if(tempPath1 != file) //after first round
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("not same in the list : "+file); 
                                                    x = true;
                                                }

                                            }
                                            System.out.println(x);
                                            if(x = true)
                                            {
                                                MyFileList.add(file);
                                                subfunction sb1 = new subfunction ();
                                                sb1.send(file);
                                            }

                                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException 
                                        {
                                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                                        }

                                    });
                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
```

As you can see, there's a `while` loop checking the condition, if the condition is true, the `FileVisitResult` will start to walk my parent directory and pick the file path, i will store the file path into a `HashSet` and the `send()` will send to my `subfunction` class. The reason i store my file path into HashSet is use for the comparison of the new file path discovered by the `FileVisitResult` and the previous discovered path which store inside the `HashSet` to avoid any duplicate file path passed to `send()` But it's not work as expected
1) How to ensure that each file path only pass to the `send()` one time ?
2) Any idea for ensure that the `FileVisitResult` will only discover the file once and will not touch back the same file during the second iteration

Comment: put every analyzed  file name is a Set, for further iterations, check first if the file candidate is in the set or not

Comment: You should probably compare `Path` equality with `equals()` , not `==` .